# Ionic async function not working

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

```
 submit_form(){
    console.log(this.check_mobile());
  }
  async function check_mobile(){
    if(this.signup.mobile != ''){
      var link = 'https://www.example.com/Android/check_mobile';
      var post_data = JSON.stringify({mobile: this.signup.mobile});
      this.http.post(link, post_data).map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => {
        if(data == 0){
          return await false;
        }
        else{
          return await true;
        }
      });
    }
    else{
      return false;
    }
  }
```

Anyone can please tell me why it is not working? How can I make it workable? Sorry for my weak English.

Answer (score 0):

First `return await true` or `return await false` is redudant. You can just do `return true` or `return false`, in fact you don't even need `await`/`async` here.

It does not work because you're using an `Observable` and you're not waiting for it. Use a `Promise` instead (you may need to import `rxjs/add/operator/toPromise`).

```
function check_mobile(){
    if(this.signup.mobile != '') {
        var link = 'https://www.example.com/Android/check_mobile';
        var post_data = JSON.stringify({mobile: this.signup.mobile});

        return this.http
            .post(link, post_data)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .toPromise()
            .then(data => {
                if(data == 0) {
                    return false;
                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }
            });
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or using `await` :

```
async function check_mobile(){
    if(this.signup.mobile != '') {
        var link = 'https://www.example.com/Android/check_mobile';
        var post_data = JSON.stringify({mobile: this.signup.mobile});

        const data = await this.http
            .post(link, post_data)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .toPromise();

        if(data == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```